# Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

Tags: objective-c, ipad, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm working on In-App purchases to my iPad app. I am able to receive the `productsRequest:didReceiveResponse` method, and receive the array of products.

My problem arises when I add a SKPayment to the SKPaymentQueue. After I add the product to the queue, in the `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions` method the transactions always have the state SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed.

I NSLog the `transaction.error` and this is what it returns:

> Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"
>   UserInfo=0x339120 {NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot connect to iTunes
>   Store}.

And also i am not able to add any new test user in Manage User.

Any solution is most welcome.
Thanks

Comment: "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" error can appear if your device is jailbroken (as it was in my case).

Answer (score 6):

This problem may also occur if your app is in Sandbox and your AppStore account isn't valid for Sandbox environment. In my case I was logged into AppStore with my **private account** and each time I tried to make purchase I got the same error as you.

So solution is:

- log out from your AppStore account (from Settings)
- go to your app and try to make purchase
- when app asks you for Apple ID choose "Use Existing Apple ID" and login with your **Sandbox account**

Comment: thank you @Josip B. Logging out of iTunes via device, and in again with sandbox account as you suggested worked for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answers, make sure you run on a device and not on the simulator. That solved the issue for me.